# How can I add an ActionListener to a JButton in a static instance?

Tags: java, swing

Nothing I've been able to find anywhere is working, and the code seems to differ from how you would do it in an applet, which I'm used to. I'm new to swing. How can I add an ActionListener (is that it? Or am I looking for something else?) to my JButtons?  (I'm not sure what is causing the `code` block to go all wonky like that, I can't fix it.)

`

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Main implements ActionListener{

static String answerOne = "";
static String answerTwo = "";
static boolean answerable = false;
static int labelX = 240, labelY = 48;
static int questionWrite = 0;
static String text = "Welcome! I will ask simple, two-answer questions, and you will answer them. Simple as that. ";
static int charIndex = 0;

private static void createAndShowGUI() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("FrameDemo");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JLabel emptyLabel = new JLabel("");
    emptyLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 225));
    frame.getContentPane().add(emptyLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

    frame.setLayout(null);
    frame.setResizable(false);

    JPanel buttons = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    final JButton buttonOne = new JButton(answerOne);
    final JButton buttonTwo = new JButton(answerTwo);
    final JButton buttonThree = new JButton("Continue");
    buttonThree.setActionCommand("continue");

    if (answerable == true) {
    buttons.add(buttonOne);
    buttons.add(buttonTwo);
    } else {
        buttons.add(buttonThree);
    }

    frame.add(buttons);

    final JLabel centerText = new JLabel("<html>");
    frame.add(centerText);

    buttons.reshape(50, 185, 200, 40);
    centerText.reshape(10, 10, 280, 160);

    Timer timer = new Timer(50, new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String labelText = centerText.getText();
        labelText += text.charAt(charIndex);
        centerText.setText(labelText);
        charIndex++;
        if (charIndex >= text.length()) {
            ((Timer)e.getSource()).stop();
        }

        Object buttonClicked = e.getSource();
        if(buttonClicked == buttonOne) {
            System.out.println("One.");
        }
        else if(buttonClicked == buttonTwo) {
            System.out.println("Two.");
        }
        else if(buttonClicked == buttonThree) {
            System.out.println("Continuing.");
        }

        //writeNext(Text to write, button one text, button two text, yes/no or "continue"); 
        switch(questionWrite) {
        case 0:
            writeNext("Welcome! I will ask simple, two-answer questions, and you will answer them. Simple as that. ", null, null, false);
            break;
        case 1:
            writeNext("Is Canada the largest country?", "Yes", "No,", true);
            break;
        case 2:
            writeNext("Have humans been to Mars?", "Yes", "No", true);
            break;
        }
    }

});

    timer.start();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
        }
    });



}
public static void writeNext(String textM, String answerOneM, String answerTwoM, boolean answerableM) {
        text = textM;
        answerOne = answerOneM;
        answerTwo = answerTwoM;
        answerable = answerableM;
    }

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

}
```

}`

Comment: Don't use static methods and static variables. This is a terrible design. It looks like most of your code comes from the Swing tutorial examples, so what not follow the examples completely then you wouldn't have this problem. The examples create a panel to add to the frame, then all you code is contained in the panel class.

Comment: `frame.pack()` and `frame.setVisible()` should be called after adding components.

Comment: You're correct, this is among my first times using Swing. I've always done Applets and LWJGL before. Where am I calling `createAndShowGUI()` then? The only place it works is in the `main` method...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        //action listener here
    }
});
```

Since you have to pass in an object to `addActionListener`, you can't do that from your static context. So you make an instance of an anonymous class and pass that in with your action event handler.

Alternatively, you can write the `actionPerformed` method in your class. It's probably best to give it a constructor to identify it though.

```
private int button;
public Main(int button)
{
    this.button = button;
}
```

Then to add the action listener:

```
button.addActionListener(new Main(1)); //or pass it 2, 3, 4 ... just some unique integer
```

Inside your actionPerformed you can read the integer you passed in.

```
if(this.button==1)
{
    //do button 1 stuff
}
```

Comment: @IHazABone yeah, then you have a different action listener for each button.

Comment: So for the alternative, in the actionPerformed method, what am I doing to detect which button is pressed and what to do with it?

Comment: @IHazABone you can create a constructor for main to accept some kind of variable to identify which button it's for and assign it to an instance variable. Then read the instance variable in actionPerformed so that you know which button it's for.

Comment: @IHazABone updating answer outlining this procedure a little bit

Comment: @IHazABone if the buttons all have different text on them, then `e.getActionCommand()` will also get the text that is on the button. So you can use that to identify them as well.